# Check for matching values across 2 fields

Tags: mysql

I am trying to think of a query that will search a table for matching values across 2 fields.

For example, what would be the query to identity tbl_id 202 and tbl_id 203 as having matching values in both tbl_row and tbl_col?

[image: db screen shot]

Thanks

tatty27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct t1.tbl_id
from
    tbl as t1
    inner join tbl as t2
        on t1.tbl_row = t2.tbl_row
        and t1.tbl_col = t2.tbl_col
        and t1.tbl_id <> t2.tbl_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the cleanest way to do it, as it'll double-up on the number of rows returned, but it'll show you the dupes. Assuming the table name is tbl:

select t1.*, t2.* from tbl t1, tbl t2 where t1.tbl_row = t2.tbl_row and t1.tbl_col = t2.tbl_col;

Answer (score 0):

```
Select T1.tbl_id, T2.tbl_id
FROM Table T1, Table T2 
WHERE T1.tbl_row = T2.tbl_row and T1.tbl_col = T2.tbl_col and T1.tbl_id <> T2.tbl_id
```